# содержимое bootstrap таблицы не во всю ширину таблицы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Имею таблицу, в которой содержимое шире ширины окна браузера. Нужно было сделать горизонтальную полосу прокрутки. Реализовал ее следующим образом: (дописал display: block; max-width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">
....
</table>
```

Все хорошо, прокрутка работает, но в случаях, когда содержимое таблицы меньше ширины окна браузера, то справа остается зазор. Ширина таблицы всегда во всю ширину экрана, а вот содержимое не растягивается во всю ширину, а сжимается к левой стороне.

Как растянуть содержимое по всей ширине в случае, когда ширина содержимого меньше окна браузера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант решения нашел следующее: обернуть `<table></table>` в `<div class="table-responsive"></div>`